# Jquery put specific atrr in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom

I have class .canvas has image with class .img-bg and they might have `<div class="recntangle">`. I want to get JSON with all source of images with style left and height of .rectangle if there are `<div class="recntangle">`

If image/`<div class="canvas">`  haven't this `<div class="recntangle">` are omit. If image has two or more classes I want to get two objects with one source and two style attributes.

I have code like this

```
<div class="canvas">
  <img class="img-bg" src="test.jpg">

  <div class="rectangle ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="left: 10px; height: 341px;">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="canvas">
  <img class="img-bg" src="example.jpg">
</div>

<div class="canvas">
  <img class="img-bg" src="image.jpg">
    <div class="rectangle ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="left: 54px height: 321px;">
      <div class="close"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle ui-draggable ui-resizable" style="left: 43px  height: 295px;">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
  </div>
```

And script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    jsonObj = [];
    $('.img-bg').map(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $next = $this.next('.rectangle');
        var src = $this.attr("src");
        var left = $next.css('left');
        var height = $next.css('height')
        item ={}
        item ["src"] = src;
        item ["left"] = left;
        item ["height"] = height;

        jsonObj.push(item); 
    }).get();

console.log(jsonObj);
```

I want output like this

```
0: Object
height: "341px"
left: "10px"
src: "test.jpg"
1: Object
height: "321px"
left: "54px"
src: "image.jpg"
2: Object
height: "295"
left: "43px"
src: "image.jpg"
```

Comment: I'm really curious, why do you have all your markup inside canvas elements ?

Comment: It's not a canvas element, it's a `<div>` with a class called `canvas`.

Comment: It was more, this is for create something like jcrop. It's drawning rectangle on img

Comment: @SparoHawk - Jeezes, I guess I have to pay more attention, I just noticed "canvas" and thought "what a strange way to do things" !

Comment: It was calles diffrent it's not matter i want to get only atrributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example code of what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jsonObj = [];
    $('.img-bg').map(function () {
        var self = this;
        var next = $(this).nextAll('.rectangle');

        if (next.length > 0) {
            next.map(function () {
                item = {};
                item.src = self.src;
                item.left = $(this).css('left');
                item.height = $(this).css('height');

                jsonObj.push(item);
            });
        }
    });

    console.log(jsonObj);
});
```

Do note you have an error in your HTML. The two bottom `<div class="rectangle">` have malformed CSS styles, they have a `;` missing between the `left` and `height` styles.